# How to use common src folder for two different modules in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to share common code for different modules in android studio? And will simply override the resources of that module .Can I do that?

[image]

I want this java directory to be available for another module? In case  I want any change in layout will override that layout file in other module. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Just create a shared Library module. Then add it as a dependency for your other modules.

File > New > New module > Android Library.

Comment: is it possible to make it without creating library?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not. But why don't you want to use a library? That's the easiest and cleanest way to share code and resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gradle plugin sourceset [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet).

It would look something like this

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
```

Then add something like (I've not tested this)

```
    android.sources{
       main{
          java.source{
             srcDir += "blah/blah/main/java"
             srcDir += "blah/blah/other/java"
          }
      }
   }
```